# Explaining the phrase 書｛か｝き込｛こ｝みによると

Tags: grammar, translation

I have translated the phrase 書き込みによると which, and if I'm right, means "According to the writing". I want to know more about the structure and grammar rules used here. I found it in [this](http://www.excite.co.jp/News/chn_soc/20150122/Recordchina_20150122057.html) article.

Comment: What exactly do you need clarification on?  NOUN+によると is generally translated as such.

Comment: So  書き込み is simply a noun.. I thought it is 2 words. Now と part is not very clear to me..

Comment: Sry... couldn't get back in time.  You got a good answer though. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

書き込みによると means "according to the entry/note."

書き込み = (handwritten) note; post; jotting; entry.

によると = a JLPT 1 grammar point that means "according to". You can read more on this grammatical form [here](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=niyoruto).

Hope this helps!

Comment: These days, 書き込み often refers to online posts; like YouTube or blog comments. Also known as 投稿{とうこう}.

Comment: Good point, let me add that!